# list() in a single line, can't introduce /newlines

Tags: list, beautifulsoup, scrape

as a project im coding to web scrape a site with statistics of certain monsters from a game, the problem is that when i append the data to a list it gets printed in the form of a very long single line.
I already tried ***.append(clean_data.getText().replace('\n', "\\n"))***.
Something to take into account is that if i don't use the .getText() I append a lot of ***[td***] and ***[tr]*** tags into the list and it gets very messy.
I think the problem here is that the text im getting is being treated as plain text so when i replace **\n** with **\\n** it gets replaced directly as **\\n** like it doesnt recognize the **\\n**.

My code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://guildstats.eu/monsters?world=Yonabra'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

monsters = ('adult goannas', 'young goannas', 'manticores', 'feral sphinxes', 'ogre ruffians', 'ogre rowdies', 'ogre sages', 'dogs')
finding_td = soup.find_all('td', string=monsters)
list_of_monsters = []
for looking_for_parent in finding_td:
    parent_tr = looking_for_parent.find_parents('tr')
    for clean_data in parent_tr:

        list_of_monsters.append(clean_data.getText().replace('\n', " "))

print(list_of_monsters)
```

It gives the following output:

```
[' 7 adult goannas  2020-05-28 1519 0 736893 133 ', ' 222 dogs  2020-05-27 143 0 40043 0 ', ' 298 feral sphinxes  2020-05-28 1158 1 480598 152 ', ' 498 manticores  2020-05-28 961 1 299491 68 ', ' 581 ogre rowdies  2020-05-28 306 0 188324 13 ', ' 582 ogre ruffians  2020-05-29 217 0 121964 7 ', ' 583 ogre sages  2020-05-28 156 0 63489 8 ', ' 911 young goannas  2020-05-28 1880 0 972217 74 ']
```

i want it to be more like this:

```
[' 7 adult goannas  2020-05-28 1519 0 736893 133 '
' 222 dogs  2020-05-27 143 0 40043 0 '
' 298 feral sphinxes  2020-05-28 1158 1 480598 152 '
' 498 manticores  2020-05-28 961 1 299491 68 '
' 581 ogre rowdies  2020-05-28 306 0 188324 13 '
' 582 ogre ruffians  2020-05-29 217 0 121964 7 '
' 583 ogre sages  2020-05-28 156 0 63489 8 '
' 911 young goannas  2020-05-28 1880 0 972217 74 ']
```

Comment: `pprint(list_of_monsters)` after `from pprint import pprint`. Also, you get nice output just with `pd.read_html('https://guildstats.eu/monsters?world=Yonabra')[0]` after `import pandas as pd` you can then drop any unwanted columns from the returned df

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to change the delimiter for the array - instead of `,`, you want a new line. As @QHarr mentioned, you can use the python **[`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)** to print the results in a better format.

Try:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from pprint import pprint
url = 'https://guildstats.eu/monsters?world=Yonabra'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
monsters = ('adult goannas', 'young goannas', 'manticores', 'feral sphinxes', 'ogre ruffians', 'ogre rowdies', 'ogre sages', 'dogs')
finding_td = soup.find_all('td', string=monsters)
list_of_monsters = []
for looking_for_parent in finding_td:
    parent_tr = looking_for_parent.find_parents('tr')
    for clean_data in parent_tr:
        list_of_monsters.append(clean_data.getText().replace("\n", " "))
pprint(list_of_monsters)
```

This gives:

```
[' 7 adult goannas  2020-05-28 1519 0 736893 133 ',
 ' 222 dogs  2020-05-27 143 0 40043 0 ',
 ' 298 feral sphinxes  2020-05-28 1158 1 480598 152 ',
 ' 498 manticores  2020-05-28 961 1 299491 68 ',
 ' 581 ogre rowdies  2020-05-28 306 0 188324 13 ',
 ' 582 ogre ruffians  2020-05-29 217 0 121964 7 ',
 ' 583 ogre sages  2020-05-28 156 0 63489 8 ',
 ' 911 young goannas  2020-05-28 1880 0 972217 74 ']
```

The `\n` characters you obtained are already new line characters. There is no need to add the extra escape character in python. As you have tried, `replace("\n", " ")` already gives you the desired `replace` effect. Also, since you're printing an array, even though the element ends with a new line, it will still be printed as `\n`. `pprint` will not have any effect on the original array, only printing it in a better format.